# Get any users email

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I'm using to get the email for the current user.

```
string to;
MembershipUser username;
username = Membership.GetUser();
to = username.Email;
```

However when I try to pass a variable to get another users info I get an error.
Seems that Membership.Getuser() only works for the current user and not for another user.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to get the email of another user. Not the current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [another method `Membership.GetUser(string username)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx) which gets a `MembershipUser` by username.

There is [yet another one `Membership.GetUser(object providerUserKey)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152019.aspx) which gets a user by whatever you've configured/coded to be `providerUserKey`.

Take your pick.

Comment: Sometimes I want to strangle asp.net with my bare hands and watch the life fade from it's eyes.... 

I tried that before and got an error about it wanting a guid. So I tried it again and it's working. Thanks bud.